# GuitarBots - Firefox/Wine - UnityWebPlayer

Tags: wine, firefox, games, plugins, webapps

I've been trying to use unity web player in this website: guitarbots.com. I'm running mozilla firefox 29.0 in wine 1.6.1. After I installed the unity plugin I got this error message.

I'v been looking for a way to fix it but nothig seems to work well. Additionally I'm not sure how to remove the plugin after is intalled in order to install a different one.

Thanks.

[image: Unity web player - broken]